# What does this formula count?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know what objects is the formula $$n \binom{n - 1}{k}, \text{ with } n \neq 0 \text{ and } k \leq n,$$
counting.

Comment: We have $n$ different-flavoured doughnuts. We want to pick $1$ of them to eat for breakfast, and $k$ of them to eat for lunch.

Comment: The number of ways to choose a group of $n-1$ unique elements from a bundle of $n$ such identical groups, and then choose $k$ out of these $n-1$ elements.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm a bit confused. Is it the number of all possible ways we can choose these $1 + k$ donuts?

Comment: Yes, the expression counts the number of ways we can choose these $k+1$ doughnuts and distribute them between breakfast and lunch. By the way, we could instead choose $k+1$ doughnuts, and then choose the one we have for breakfast. That can be done in $(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}$ ways. That gives us a combinatorial proof of the identity $n\binom{n-1}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The usual wording is in terms of committees. Too bureaucratic, too close to one of the more unpleasant aspects of academic life.